# Final Cut Pro- Reopen Library and Entire Timeline is Gone!

Tags: final-cut-pro

I was working with a library, arranged all my clips, audio, etc. and had a great 6 minute long video ready to go.

When I closed the library, I shut my computer off. After I rebooted, I went to reopen the library and all of the files are still part of the library, but all of the clip arranging and everything I did to it- the entire timeline- is gone!

It's just completely blank as if all I did was drop files into the library and never started working on anything from within the timeline.

What happened!? Is there any way to view all of my timeline? That's like 12 hours worth of work!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeline for which you are looking is actually called a "Project".  Projects are stored within events, which are in turn stored within a library.  Just opening a library (from within the finder, for instance) will not necessarily open your project.  To do that, you need to twirl down the disclosure triangle next to your Library in the event manager, select the event upon which you were working, and then double click the Project name to load it in the timeline.  Also, make sure that you are connected to any drives or network storage locations that you might have stored media to when you created the project.